# UICollectionView and SDWebImage, crash when scrolling through lot of images

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, sdwebimage

We have an app built on the iOS 10 SDK. It is presenting images in a UICollectionView and the images are loaded using the SDWebImage framework. It works well, but users have reported that the app suddenly crashes from time to time when scrolling back and forward through the images in the UICollectionView.

We have at last been able to reproduce the error on an iPhone 6 device with the mobile data connection slowed down to 3G.

**What happens:**
While scrolling quickly up and down through the images, quicker than they can be loaded from the server, suddenly the app crashes back to the iOS desktop. This could happen quickly, after a while, or sometimes it does not happen at all - very inconsistent.

**What we have done so far:**

- Used instruments to check for leaks, the memory consumption is stable and lies constantly around 200Mb.
- There are no calls to didReceiveMemoryWarning
- We use CrashLytics to detect crashes and exceptions, nothing is logged.
- The console or the debugger does not indicate any errors and no exceptions, Xcode just reports that it lost the connection to the phone when the app crashes.

Could anyone suggest an approach for further troubleshooting to nail this?

Stefan

Comment: "The console or the debugger does not indicate any errors and no exceptions, Xcode just reports that it lost the connection to the phone when the app crashes." I'd tend to say it may be in fact a memory/CPU warning (just didn't have enough time to be told to XCode). I got a similar issue, and I removed a few call that were consuming (doing useless call), it worked. It happened especially on a old device. If you can, try to find a old device, with low RAM/CPU, like an iPod Touch 6thG, and old iPhone 5 (oldest one). It may be easier to reproduce.

Comment: @Larme - Yes, it seems to be more easy to reproduce the problem on older hardware where RAM and CPU is more limited recourses. The problem is probably related to the fact that there is a lot going on in the background while scrolling the collectionview. Metadata and the thumbnail images are loaded from the server ad-hoc. From what we have read, problems like these are mostly related to memory issues, problem is that we have absolutely nothing to work from.

Comment: If you still want to support these old device, I think the only way to to get an `[UIDevice isSlow]` method (checking the model?) and do specific stuff when it's the case, like maybe not loading if the acceleration if the user is scrolling and "not stopped" and not already loaded? This could avoid you many calls. I did that on a project where scrolling wasn't smooth: CollectionView inside TableView (the reload iss consuming), so I used a ScrollView (breaking then the reuse of the table), and load only if scroll stopped or has been loaded once For now it does the trick (not fully tested).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with `SDWebImage`. For me, it was because I let `SDWebImage` keep loading too many images at once. After adding

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    [self.imageView sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad];
}
```

the issue disappeared.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel, I will try this out and see if this could have a positive effect on this behaviour.